# Java write value to another running process

Tags: java

I'm trying to change value of address memory of another running proccess in java. 
I did have known process is running, but how to access the static address of the process and alter? 
Like something that : writeByte(process, address, (int) value) 
Address is something like: 0x005B8980

```
String line;
    String pidInfo ="";
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");


    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        pidInfo+=line; 
    }

    input.close();

    if(pidInfo.contains("APP"))
    {

    // DO send bytes to APP

    }
```

Comment: AFAIK if you are able to get an `Unsafe` through reflection, you are able to copy an object to a memory pointer.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking the wrong question. What's your use case? Why can't you use other inter process communication methods?

Comment: Sometimes, my app communicates via socket to this process, when they are in remote system. But in this case, i can't retrieve and change some values, and it's local machine

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396664/shared-memory-between-two-jvms, or is there something here that's different than that?

Comment: yea, it's different, cuz another process is from third part, and its not build in java

Comment: by using java, i just wanna inject bytes to another running process